# $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{f(N)}{N \choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

I'd like a way to simplify this, if there is any:
$$
 \lim_{N, N_+ \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{f(N, N_+)}{N \choose k} \qquad f(N, N_+) = \frac{1}{2}[N + C(2N_+-N)], C>0, N_+< N \in ℕ
$$

I found a solution to a problem that seems very similar [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/17236), but I don't understand it and it's only similar to my problem. I'm interested in the behavior around $\infty$, i.e. is it ~$e^N$...

Comment: What is $N_+$ representing in terms of $N$?

Comment: @Diger it's a natural number just as $N$ such that $N_+ < N$. I'll add it to the quastion. The original problem had $N_+ + N_- = N$, but I thought that carrying around 3 variables when 2 will do the trick is useless

Comment: There is no simple formula for the partial sum of binomial numbers. But it obviously diverges for $N\to\infty$.

Comment: You should not encumber the problem with the $f(N,N_+)$. Just use some $M$.

Comment: When the upper bound is $N$, the sum equals $2^N$, which is not $\sim e^N$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(N, N_+)>0$, $$ \sum_{k = 0}^{f(N, N_+)}{N \choose k}f(N, N_+)>N\to\infty.$$

Comment: I guess i poorly worded my question. I know it's diverging but i was wondering more about what it diverges as. What is the divergent behavior. I'm compelled to use stirling, but it only works for the $N$ and not for the $k$ as $k$ starts small in the summation. But if there is no simple way to get that, then I guess I'm screwed

Answer (score 0):

We can approximate a symmetric binomial law by a Gaussian.

$$B\left(k;n,\frac12\right)\sim\sqrt{\frac2{\pi N}}e^{-2(k-N/2)^2/N}$$

and

$$\sum_{k=0}^MB\left(k;n,\frac12\right)\sim\sqrt{\frac2{\pi N}}\int_{-N/2}^{M-N/2}e^{-2k^2/N}dk
\\=\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac N2}\left(M-\frac2N\right)\right)-\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\dfrac2N}\left(-\frac N2\right)\right).$$

Then the sum you are requesting is this $\text{cdf}$ of the binomial, times $2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Just some partial answer...

Obviously $\binom{N}{k}=0$ if $k>N$, so you only need to consider $f(N,N_+) \leq N$. Also: $\binom{N}{k} = \binom{N}{N-k}$.

Therefore it makes sense to rewrite your function as $f(N,N_+)=\frac{N}{2} + K$ for some integer $-N/2 \leq K \leq N/2$ and we can assume $N$ being even (by adding a unit from the other term). You should then distinguish the following cases

1. $|K| \ll N/2$. It suffices to consider $K>0$ since the other case just differs by an additive sign. We can now split as follows
   $$ \sum_{k=0}^{N/2+K} \binom{N}{k} = \sum_{0 \leq k \leq N/2} \binom{N}{k} + \sum_{k=1}^K \binom{N}{N/2+k}$$
   and notice that the first term is easily evaluated to $\frac{1}{2} \left( 2^N + \binom{N}{N/2} \right)$ (by symmetry), while for the second you can probably apply some approximation when $k$ is small and $N$ large.
2. $K=N/2-K'$ where $0<K'\ll N/2$. This is equivalent to
   $$\sum_{k=0}^{N/2+K} \binom{N}{k} =  \sum_{k=0}^{N-K'} \binom{N}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k} - \sum_{k=N-K'+1}^N \binom{N}{k} = 2^N - \sum_{k=0}^{K'-1} \binom{N}{k} \, ,$$
   so the case where $K$ is close to $-N/2$ i.e. $K=-N/2+K'$.
3. The intermediate case $K=N/4 + K'$ where $0 < K' \ll N/4$.

In general the cases 1 and 2 where I assumed $K,K'$ being small will probably hold even for it being some small power of $N$.